# Can't do regex matching on object on a UITextField with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, regex, xcode

Validating a password entered by the user  I´m getting the following error in Xcode:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do regex matching on object Bopster.RegisterPresenter.'

This is the method used to validate the password entered as UITextField in the ViewController

```
func isValidPassword(password: String) -> Bool {
    let passwordRegex = "^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*()\\-_=+{}|?>.<,:;~`’]{8,}$"
    debugPrint(passwordRegex)
    return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", passwordRegex).evaluate(with: self)
}
```

here I declare a property that gets the boolean value from the regex.

```
let userPasswordChecked = isValidPassword(password: password)
```

then with a conditional I decide to move or show an error:

```
if userPasswordChecked {
    //  True, store it in COStorage.
    COStorage().savePassword(pass: password)
} else {
    //  False, message to user.
    let error = "La constraseña no es valida."
    self.view?.errorLoading(error: error)
}
```

I have tried with other patterns but so far it seems that the error is with the NSPredicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have declared your `isValidPassword` method in your RegisterPresenter class the `self` refers to the instance of RegisterPresenter.

You can solve your issue simply by changing the method from `evaluate(with: self)` to `evaluate(with: password)`:

```
func isValidPassword(password: String) -> Bool {
    let passwordRegex = "^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*()\\-_=+{}|?>.<,:;~`’]{8,}$"
    debugPrint(passwordRegex)
    return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", passwordRegex).evaluate(with: password)
}
```

You want to evaluate with the password String being passed in, not with the RegisterPresenter.